# Checking if string is only letters and spaces - Python

Tags: python, contain

Trying to get python to return that a string contains ONLY alphabetic letters AND spaces

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")

if all(x.isalpha() and x.isspace() for x in string):
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
```

I've been trying `please` and it comes up as `Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no` I've used `or` instead of `and`, but that only satisfies one condition. I need both conditions satisfied. That is the sentence must contain *only letters* and *only spaces* but must have at least one of each kind. It must *not* contain any numerals.

What am I missing here for python to return both letters and spaces are only contained in the string?

Comment: A string cannot be both a letter and a space

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, then how do I get python to return that BOTH are true (there is ONLY letters and spaces? `please `Has only one space and all letters, but it doesn't return that both criteria are satisfied.

Comment: @sithlorddahlia I kinda get your question. You mean to say `hi there` is true as it has both letter and space, but `hi` or `    ` is false as they don't have both. Am I correct?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A character cannot be both an alpha **and** a space. It can be an alpha **or** a space.

To require that the string contains only alphas and spaces:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")

if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string):
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
```

To require that the string contains at least one alpha and at least one space:

```
if any(x.isalpha() for x in string) and any(x.isspace() for x in string):
```

To require that the string contains at least one alpha, at least one space, and only alphas and spaces:

```
if (any(x.isalpha() for x in string)
    and any(x.isspace() for x in string)
    and all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string)):
```

Test:

```
>>> string = "PLEASE"
>>> if (any(x.isalpha() for x in string)
...     and any(x.isspace() for x in string)
...     and all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string)):
...     print "match"
... else:
...     print "no match"
... 
no match
>>> string = "PLEASE "
>>> if (any(x.isalpha() for x in string)
...     and any(x.isspace() for x in string)
...     and all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string)):
...     print "match"
... else:
...     print "no match"
... 
match
```

Comment: Okay, then this method doesn't fit what I need. I need for BOTH to return True so that way it states `Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes` with `please `

I just tried this:
`alphabet = string.isalpha()
 spaces = string.isspace()
 if alphabet == True and spaces == True` but still no go. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please edit your original question to include your new requirements.

Comment: It's not a new requirement, it's the same requirement. Python needs to read that both only letters and spaces are in the string. Take `please `for example. It has both spaces and letters. `please` has only letters but no spaces. So both criteria aren't met.

Comment: Do you mean it needs to contain at least one letter and at least one space? Is it allowed to also contain non-letter non-space characters?

Comment: It can only contain letters and spaces. `please my email` has only letters and spaces so python should print `Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes`. `read my 5 emails` does have letters and spaces, but it has a number, so `Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no`

Comment: This is close, very close! Only I have an issue with a word and no space. `PLEASE` returns `Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes`, but it doesn't have any spaces. It's just the word.

Comment: It works for me. See my updated answer. If it's not working for you, copy and paste your new code into your original question.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for all your help and useful information! Have a great day, sir!

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution would use an `or`.

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")

if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string):
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
```

Although you have a string, you are iterating over the letters of that string, so you have one letter at a time. So, a char alone cannot be an alphabetical character AND a space at the time, but it will just need to be one of the two to satisfy your constraint.

**EDIT:** I saw your comment in the other answer. `alphabet = string.isalpha()` return `True`, if and only if *all* characters in a string are alphabetical letters. This is not what you want, because you stated that you want your code to print `yes` when execute with the string `please`, which has a space. You need to check each letter on its own, not the whole string.

Just to convince you that the code is indeed correct (well, ok, you need to execute it yourself to be convinced, but anyway):

```
>>> string = "please "
>>> if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in string):
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")


Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes
```

**EDIT 2:** Judging from your new comments, you need something like this:

```
def hasSpaceAndAlpha(string):
    return any(char.isalpha() for char in string) and any(char.isspace() for char in string) and all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in string)

>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text# ")
False
>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text")
False
>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text ")
True
```

or

```
def hasSpaceAndAlpha(string):
    if any(char.isalpha() for char in string) and any(char.isspace() for char in string) and all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in string):
        print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
    else:
        print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")

>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text# ")
Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no
>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text")
Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no
>>> hasSpaceAndAlpha("text ")
Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is an pattern matching exercise, so why not use pattern matching?

```
import re
r = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")
def test(s):
    return not r.match(s) is None
```

Or is there any requirement to use `any()` in the solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `return not r.match(s) is None` rather than `return bool(r.match(s))`?

Comment: Maybe. I prefer coding variants that can be understood with the least possible thinking when coming back to the code after a year or so. Openly dealing with the return value of `r.match()` might support this. What I really should have done differently is the name of the function ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) if you want at least one of each in the string:

```
if any(x.isalpha() for x in string) and any(x.isspace() for x in string):
```

If you want at least one of each  but no other characters you can combine `all`,`any` and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) , the following will only return `True` if we have at least one space, one alpha and contain only those characters.

```
 from string import ascii_letters

 s = input("Enter a string: ")

 tbl = {ord(x):"" for x in ascii_letters + " "}

if all((any(x.isalpha() for x in s),
   any(x.isspace() for x in s),
   not s.translate(tbl))):
    print("all good")
```

Check if there is at least one of each with `any` then translate the string, if the string is empty there are only alpha characters and spaces. This will  work for upper and lowercase.

You can condense the code to a single `if/and`:

```
from string import ascii_letters

s = input("Enter a string: ")
s_t = s.translate({ord(x):"" for x in ascii_letters})

if len(s_t) < len(s) and s_t.isspace():
    print("all good")
```

If the length of the translated string is <  original and all that is left are spaces we have met the requirement.

Or reverse the logic and translate the spaces and check if we have only alpha left:

```
s_t = s.translate({ord(" "):"" })
if len(s_t) < len(s) and s_t.isalpha():
    print("all good")
```

Presuming the string will always have more alphas than spaces, the last solution should be by far the most efficient.

Comment: @BhargavRao, maybe i was looking for a scrap ;)

Comment: Add the link to the function `any`

Answer (score 2):

```
    string = input("Enter a string: ")
    st1=string.replace(" ","").isalpha()
    if (st1):
        print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
    else:
        print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
```

Comment: Just give some description what you are writing.

Comment: in the above code . remove all space and then check the string that is it alphabetical or not. if it is alphabetical then it is alphabetical string with white spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for doing that action

```
import re


name = input('What is your name ?')

if not re.match("^[a-z A-Z]*$", name):
    print("Only Alphabet and Space are allowed")
else:
    print("Hello" ,name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove spaces and question is only alphanumeric
def isAlNumAndSpaces(string):
    return string.replace(" ","").isalnum()
strTest = input("Test a string: ")
if isAlNumAndSpaces(strTest):
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
else:
    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
```

Comment: OP .. check the additions of Arpad and lear from it how to post a complete and valid answer. End of Review.

Answer (score 0):

use a pattern match like this

> ```
> import re
> alpha_regex = "^[a-z A-Z]+$"
> if re.match(alpha_regex, string):
>    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: yes")
> else:
>    print("Only alphabetical letters and spaces: no")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

the usage of `isalpha()` is less specific than using regex.

isalpha will return true not only for [a-zA-Z] but for other alphabetic unicodes.

### **use `bool(re.match('^[a-zA-Z\s]+$', name)`**